# Visual studio oddity toolbox click drag

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, dotconnect

So, I just installed [dotConnect](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) and in the wpf editor, if I select say a button then click and drag it to the window under construction in the designer, the option to select another control already there is lost.  After that every time I click in the designer window it will place another button instead of highlighting the component or simply the last item I click and drag.

It's as if the toolbox is not letting go of my mouse function.  I'm not sure if the dotConnect is related or not but it is the last change I made to VS since it started.

Has anyone dealt with this and know how to fix it?

Edit:

I found that if I click and drag from the toolbox to a restricted area (for instance the solution explorer) and drop it, it returns to normal.  I have to do this every time I click and drag a new control into the design window.

Comment: Which dotConnect product did you install?

Comment: dotConnect for Oracle 8.3 Professional Trial

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio 2010 Express or the full version?

Comment: I'm running the full version.

Comment: Please try resetting your Visual Studio 2010 settings as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately still the same.

Comment: Did you install both applications as Administrator?

Comment: A new build (Oracle 8.3.161) became available yesterday, try installing that: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=29592

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the update as TrevorBrooks suggested, the problem went away.